# pytorch question regarding backward argument used in blitz tutorial

Tags: pytorch

A pytorch question, regarding `backward()`. In the pytorch [blitz tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py) copied and pasted below, they pass in a vector `[0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]` to `backward()` . I can intuitively guess why vector `[0.1, 1.0, 0.0001]` shape passed in is [3] , but I do not understand where the values 0.1, 1.0, 0.0001 come from. Another tutorial I looked at passes in one such that backwards on a vector is done like this : `L.backward(torch.ones(L.shape))`

```
# copied from blitz tutorial
Now in this case y is no longer a scalar. torch.autograd could not compute the full Jacobian directly, but if we just want the vector-Jacobian product, simply pass the vector to backward as argument:

v = torch.tensor([0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], dtype=torch.float)
y.backward(v)

print(x.grad)
```

If anyone can explain the reasoning for [0.1, 1.0, 0.0001], I would appreciate it.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, they are arbitrary numbers. In a tutorial, it might be better to give different non-random numbers such that the readers can notice that the output is proportional to the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document says, implicitly, grad cannot be created for non-scalar outputs. `y` is non-scalar tensor, and you cannot `y.backward()` directly. But you can pass in a vector to backward to get the `vector-Jacobian product`. If you don't want to change the grads, you can pass in a vector with all elements are ones.

```py
x = torch.tensor([2.,3.,4.], requires_grad=True)
y = x**2

y.backward() # error

y.backward(torch.tensor([1.,1.,1.])) # work
x.grad # tensor([4.,6.,8.])

# y.backward(torch.tensor([2.,2.,2.])) # change the passed vector. 
# x.grad # tensor([8.,12.,16])
```